# MySQL ORDER BY optimisation on range

Tags: mysql, optimization, range, sql-order-by

I'd like MySQL to use the index to sort these rows.

```
SELECT
  identity_ID
FROM
  identity
WHERE
  identity_modified > 1257140905
ORDER BY
  identity_modified
```

However, this is using a filesort for sorting (undesirable).

Now, if I leave off the ORDER BY clause here, the rows come out sorted *simply as a consequence of using the index to satisfy the WHERE clause*.

So, I can get the behaviour I want by leaving off the WHERE clause, but then I'm relying on MySQL's behaviour to be consistent for the rows to arrive in order, and might get stung in future simply if MySQL changes its internal behaviour.

What should I do?  Any way of telling MySQL that since the index is stored in order (b-tree) that it doesn't need a filesort for this?

The table looks like this (simplified):

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `identity` (
  `identity_ID`       int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `identity_modified` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY         (`identity_ID`),
  KEY                 `identity_modified` (`identity_modified`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 ;
```

Comment: Let me clear my understanding here, you want to sort identity_modified but not the other fields? or im missing the point

Comment: The point is, I want to retrieve all records modified since a certain date, sorted by the date they were last modified.  I don't want MySQL to have to do a filesort for this; it could have to sort the majority of the table.  A filesort shouldn't be needed since MySQL stores the index rows in order.

Comment: Can you post explains of this query with and without order by. For me it's either doing a full scan and a sort or it's using index without sorting (depending on how many records are fetched).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I have so far is to leave off the `ORDER BY` clause, and add a `FORCE INDEX (identity_modified)` to the query.  This should in theory ensure that the rows are returned in the order they are stored in the index.

It's probably not a *best practice* way to do it, but it seems to be the only way that works the way I want.

Answer (score 0):

If you change the table type to INNODB there won't be a filesort

ALTER TABLE `mydb`.`identity` ENGINE = INNODB;

But I'm not sure there's a problem with your query:
http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?24,10738,10785#msg-10785

Run your original query with EXPLAIN before and after the operation.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/using-explain.html

Comment: YES, it has an index on that column.  It is using the index for the WHERE clause, but it is not using the index to do the sorting.

Comment: Can you create a script so that we can recreate the table?

Is the query above the full one or are something missing?

Comment: Added table def to question.  Yes the query above is the full one - all I need is the identity_ID values in order of modified date, where modified date is larger than a certain value.